# Illegal state exception when putting in a Map

Tags: java, exception, illegalstateexception

I don't understand why I get the infamous "IllegalStateException" whith the following code:

```
private void mergeQueryStrings(String url, Map parameterMap) {
    String queryString = getQueryString(url);
    if(queryString!=null){
        String [] params = queryString.split("&");
        for(String param:params){
            parameterMap.put(param.split("=")[0], param.split("=")[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: On first sight I can't see anything wrong. In which line is this exception thrown?

Comment: Nothing obvious, but you have a lot of information you haven't shared.  What line is generating the exception?  What is the message from the exception?  What value(s) of `url` cause the exception to occur?  What `Map` implementation is being passed into the method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've supplied an unmodifiable map. For example, the [`ServletRequest#getParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) is immutable. If you have no control over the supplied map, then you need to create a new map, put the new items in there, return it and use it instead.

```
private Map mergeQueryStrings(String url, Map parameterMap) {
    Map newParameterMap = new HashMap(parameterMap);
    String queryString = getQueryString(url);
    if(queryString!=null){
        String [] params = queryString.split("&");
        for(String param:params){
            newParameterMap.put(param.split("=")[0], param.split("=")[1]);
        }
    }
    return newParameterMap;
}
```

If you were *actually* using the servlet request parameter map for this, then you'd like to replace the original one with help of a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` in a `Filter`. But that's a completely different story :)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should [url-decode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) the query string parts before putting them in the new map.

Comment: +1 and one more thing to note: `param.split("=")[1]` can throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the query string happens to have a parameter with no `=` in it.